# Agregar dos arreglos en forma de columnas a una matriz

Tags: python

Tengo dos arreglos

- `x= [a,b,c,d,e`]
- `y=[f,g,h,i,j]`

Quiero crear una matriz que contenga dichos arreglos como dos columnas, es decir que me aparezca así

| a | f |
| --- | --- |
| b | g |
| c | h |
| d | i |
| e | j |

Lo hago de la siguiente manera: `M = ([x], [y])` pero el resultado es que une ambos arreglos y lo que yo quiero es que se separe por columnas.

Comment: `[[x, y] for x, y in zip(lista1, lista2)]`

Comment: Estás usando numpy o alguna librería que debamos saber? O es python puro? El problema afecta sólo a la hora de mostrar la información, o a la hora de procesarla de algún modo? Faltan detalles